# Is it possible to have a non-alcoholic Gin?

Tags: taste, spirits, non-alcoholic, gin

Is it possible to have a non-alcoholic gin?  Tastes like gin but without the alcohol.  Tonic on its own just isn't the same, but as the years go by I feel the need to minimise the 'volume' in my glass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible to have a non-alcoholic Gin?

The short answer is **yes**.

> Pernod Ricard has signed a deal to launch and distribute South African/Swedish brand Ceder’s in the UK, which describes itself as a “non-alcoholic alt-gin made with classic gin and South African botanicals”.
>
> The non-alcoholic ‘spirit’ was launched in early 2017 by husband and wife team Craig Hutchison (South African) and Maria Sehlstrom (Swedish). - [Pernod Ricard ventures into non-alcoholic ‘gin’](https://www.thedrinksbusiness.com/2018/07/pernod-ricard-ventures-into-non-alcoholic-gin/)

[Seedlip](https://www.theginkin.com/2017/12/01/lets-talk-non-alcoholic-gin/) also has a non-alcoholic gin on the market but the leading flavour is clove rather than juniper as with gin and is thus not a real gin. It is more a gin alternative.

> The biggest name in non-alcoholic gin is Seedlip. Seedlip Spice 94 (£22.99, Amazon) is the closest offering Seedlip has to the ‘real thing’ — although they’re quick to offer a caveat.
>
> “It’s made like a gin with botanicals, but is definitely not a gin.” The leading flavor is clove rather than juniper as with gin.
>
> You may be familiar with non-alcoholic beer, but non-alcoholic gin is a relative newbie.

Amongst others non-alcohol gins (gin alternatives) are [Brunswick Aces](https://www.brunswickaces.com/), [Herbie Virgin](http://herbiegin.com/en/) and to a lesser degree **Teetotal G&T** as it is a pre-mix.

> Teetotal G‘n’T has all the flavour of Gin and Tonic but without the alcohol. It is made from natural ingredients and botanicals found in a good gin and tonic. - [The Temperance Spirit Company](http://ttscompany.co.uk/consumer/)

Comment: As per usual Ken you come up with the goods - the Pernod Ricard is great news and something that I will investigate further - many thanks for your time and selflessness....  go to the top of the class and collect a gold star!

Answer (score 1):

There *is* actually a non-alcoholic Gin substitute called [Seedlip](https://www.seedlipdrinks.com/) which is made in a similar way; by passing steam instead of alcohol vapour through botanicals. Unfortunately I'm not sure how available it is outside of the UK.

Please note that I am in absolutely no way connected to the company and have only tried a sip of a cocktail made with it in the past so YMMV.